# Скажите я правильно понял что происходит в функции?

Tags: javascript

```js
var field = document.querySelector('#field');
var ball  = document.querySelector('#ball');

field.onclick = function(e){

  var fieldCoords = this.getBoundingClientRect();

  var  fieldInnerCoords = {
    left: fieldCoords.left + field.clientLeft,
    top:  fieldCoords.top + field.clientTop
  }

  ball.style.left = e.clientX -  fieldInnerCoords.left + 'px';
  ball.style.top = e.clientY -  fieldInnerCoords.top + 'px';
}
```

```css
 #field {
      width: 150px;
      border: 10px groove black;
      background-color: #00FF00;
      position: relative;
      margin: 300px auto;
    }

    #ball {
      position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
<div id="field">
  <img src="https://js.cx/clipart/ball.svg" width="40" height="40" id="ball"> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
</div>
```

1. **field.onclick** происходит событие **click** первым аргументом всегда будет объект **Event** который содержит детали события
2. У объекта **Event** есть  свойства **clientX** и **clientY**  которые означают координаты курсора в момент клика (относительно окна)
3. В переменную **fieldCoords** присваиваем объект который содержит координаты элемента field;
4. Мы хотим чтобы мяч перемещался по полю, но не убегал за поле
5. Для этого из переменной **fieldCoords** надо получить свойства которые содержат в переменной это можно сделать так fieldCoords.left и fieldCoords.top которые запишем соответственно в **left** и **top**
6. Затем в **left** и **top** прибавим рамки для этого есть свойства **clientLeft** и **clientTop** получается field.clientLeft
7. Мяч у нас находится в переменной **ball** который позиционирован абсолютно то будет в левом верхнем углу переменной **field**
8. Получаем **css** cсвойство **left**  и присваиваем координаты курсора в момент клика (относительно окна) **clientX** от которого вычитаем переменную  **fieldInnerCoords**  которые содержит координаты элемента относительно окна которому прибавили рамку l**eft: fieldCoords.left + field.clientLeft** и так как **left**  это **css** свойство ему надо указать единицу измерения желательно в **px** так как  координаты элемента в пикселях

Правильно я понял что происходит в этой функции ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да. Очень хорошее и детальное описание происходящего.

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка в пункте `4`.

Левый верхний угол картинки с мячом просто переносится в место клика мыши.

Какой-то сумбур в пункте `8`.

Этот пункт можно описать проще: перевод из координат относительно страницы в координаты относительно клиентской части поля.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, чего мы хотим, но пункт 4 не совсем соответствует действительности:

[image: скриншот мяча на гринице] [image: скриншот мяча снаружи]

А так, описание вроде верное.

Comment: ♦ а как правильно сделать ?

Comment: @Leks, либо пололожить ещё один элемент внутрь, либо вычитать отступы и размер мяча для правого края.

Comment: а написать аааа ?